# delphi how to setup tcpserver to receive string data

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, tcplistener

i have to setup a tcp service to handle some clients request

all requests are  come in Hex string packets with length of 1099 byte and also all start with `00D0` and end with `00000000`

```
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, 1099, False);

    RStr:='';
    for I := 0 to length(data)-1 do
      RStr := RStr + chr(data[i]);

    if(copy(RStr,1,4)='00D0') and (copy(RStr,1091,8)='00000000') then
      begin
       Memo14.Lines.Add( 'Frame added to database.' );
      end
    else
      begin
       Memo14.Lines.Add( 'error invalid Frame ...' );
      end;
end;
```

the server receive data 1099 byte packets but just `error invalid Frame ...` showing.

what is my code problem !?

PS: the client is sending data to server continuously,i mean client receive data from 3rd party and send to server, so its possible to data is not started from first of a packet! so i must drop some data to reach packet first `00D0`!

Comment: Is the data a string in hex format? Maybe you mean to do `(RStr, 1, 2) = $00$D0`?

Comment: no, data are converting to string (RStr, 1, 4) = '0D00'

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint and look at `RStr` in the debugger on the line with the `if`? Are the first 4 characters what you expect? What about the last 8?

Comment: @KenWhite the `0D00` and `00000000` is there in input string ,but not at first and end.i must drop some data to reach the `00D0` and then every 1099 byte start with `00D0` and ends with `00000000`...

Comment: @roozgar see, these are the kind of details you should have provided from the very beginning. They effect the kinds of answers people give you

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, sorry :) i wrote the P.S. a bit late..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indy has a `BytesToString()` function, in the `IdGlobal` unit, so you don't need to convert a `TIdBytes` to a `string` manually:

```
RStr := BytesToString(data);
```

A `string` is typically 1-indexed (unless you are compiling for mobile and don't use `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}`), so `copy(RStr,1091,8)` should be using 1092 instead of 1091, since you are reading 1099 bytes instead of 1098 bytes:

```
copy(RStr,1092,8)
```

But, Indy has `TextStartsWith()` and `TextEndsWith()` functions, also in the `IdGlobal` unit, so you don't need to extract and compare substrings manually:

```
if TextStartsWith(RStr, '00D0') and TextEndsWith(RStr, '00000000') then
```

Now, that being said, if your socket data really is textual in nature and not binary, you should use the `TIdIOHandler.ReadString()` method instead of the `TIdIOHandler.ReadBytes()` method:

```
RStr := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(1099);
```

Alternatively, `TIdIOHandler` also has `WaitFor()` and `ReadLn()` methods for reading delimited text, eg:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor('00D0');
RStr := '00D0' + AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn('00000000') + '00000000';
```

or

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor('00D0');
RStr := '00D0' + AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor('00000000', True, True);
```

Lastly, `TIdTCPServer` is a multithreaded componnet, its `OnExecute` event is fired in the context of a worker thread, not the main UI thread.  As such, you MUST sync with the main UI thread when accessing the UI, such as via the RTL's `TThread.Queue()` or `TThread.Synchronize()` class methods, or Indy's `TIdNotify` or `TIdSync` classes, etc.  Bad things *can* and usually *do* happen when you access UI controls from outside of the main UI thread.

**UPDATE**: in comments, you say the data is actually in bytes, not text characters.  And that you need to drop bytes before you start reading records.  In that case, you should not be converting the bytes to a `string` at all.  Handle the bytes as-is instead, eg:

```
procedure TForm2.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  data: TIdBytes;
  b: Byte;
begin
  b := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  repeat
    if b <> $00 then Exit;
    b := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadByte;
  until b = $D0;

  SetLength(data, 2);
  data[0] = $00;
  data[1] = $D0;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, 1097, True);

  repeat
    if {(PWord(@data[0])^ = $D000)}(data[0] = $00) and (data[1] = $D0)
      and (PUInt32(@data[1091])^ = $00000000) then
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Memo14.Lines.Add( 'Frame added to database.' );
        end;
      );
    end else
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Memo14.Lines.Add( 'error invalid Frame ...' );
        end;
      );
    end;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, 1099, False);
  until False;
end;
```

Comment: thank you for the complete answer, the input data is in bytes,for this i convert the bytes to string in my code , is `WaitFor` working like you used(string parameters) or i must use like this `WaitFor('$00$D0')` !?

Comment: ok,i dont need to convert to string in first step , but how can i work with `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor` in byte input , i looked but never find a document for `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor` !!!

Comment: "*the input data is in bytes*" - then you would need to convert the individual bytes to actual hex strings, such as with `IntToHex()`, which you are not actually doing. Better, don't convert to a string at all. But you can't really use `WaitFor()` for binary data.

Comment: thank you for update, please look at the PS of my post and also the comment i wrote for ken.